# Get the value of a key if exists in one array elements in a variant column in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a variant column which has array of objects. I need to get the value of orgId (iVtXg1iwVmT9Q)from this array. How do I do that? There will be only one **orgId** but I don't know the element index. The below example the answer is mycolumn[1].data.orgId

```
[{
           "data": {
              "isCustomerAuthenticated": false,
              "visibility": "open"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/2-0-0"
       },
       {
           "data": {
               "orgId": "iVtXg1iwVmT9Q",
               "site": "us-abcde.qa",
               "stage": "staging"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/1-0-0"
       },
       {
           "data": {
               "onboardingType": "form"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/1-0-1"
       }
   ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given you don't know which element you need to unroll them all via [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html), and then filter out the ones that don't match.

```
SELECT f.value:data:orgId::text as ordId
FROM table t,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input => t.mycolumn)) f
WHERE f.value:data:orgId::text IS NOT NULL;
```

With this pattern you can select any of the other elements you want like `site` or `stage` as well.

```
SELECT 
    f.value:data:orgId::text AS ordId
    f.value:data:site::text AS site
    f.value:data:staging::text AS staging
FROM table t,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(input => t.mycolumn)) f
WHERE f.value:data:orgId::text IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: "QUALIFY" requires window function, no? I think WHERE is enough here.

Comment: OMG I have over though it, hattip, a WHERE is enough yes! I think I am almost always aggregating/windowing, so over use QUALIFY...

Answer (score -1):

"Naive" text approach:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(ARRAY_TO_STRING(col,''), '"orgId":"([^"]*)"',1,1,'e',1)
FROM T;
-- iVtXg1iwVmT9Q
```

Data preparation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T AS 
SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{
           "data": {
              "isCustomerAuthenticated": false,
              "visibility": "open"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/2-0-0"
       },
       {
           "data": {
               "orgId": "iVtXg1iwVmT9Q",
               "site": "us-abcde.qa",
               "stage": "staging"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/1-0-0"
       },
       {
           "data": {
               "onboardingType": "form"
           },
           "schema": "jsonschema/1-0-1"
       }
   ]') AS col;
```